# How do I make codeigniter to load a HTML project?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a project which is this one:
[image]

Its just a html webpage with the features of letting the user modify the product the way they want, it currently does not have any backend.

I have done this:

In my app/controllers I have a made one controller named:desing

it has this

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class desing extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/desing_tool', FALSE);
    $this->load->view('index');
  }
```

}

I have the third party project in the folder third_party and my routing settings are this:

```
$route['desing'] = 'desing';
```

but it doesnt load, I want to add a shopping cart, I will make a cms but I cant make code igniter load this.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Unless you've [setup](https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/) your server so `HTML` files can read `PHP`, you can't. You'll need a `PHP` file or `AJAX`.

Comment: I did save the index as .php too, but It didnt work

Comment: To change your views to html `$this->load->view('example.html');`  But I would not use index as a view because the main index.php is for codeigniter

Comment: the same, 404 error, gosh

Comment: Try name your class and file name like `Desing.php` and `class Desing extends CI_Controller {}` the first letter must be only upper case I think you meant to spell it like `Design`

Comment: nope, the same friend, 404

Comment: this is a full functioning project made with:

Angular Js
UI Elements (HTML5, CSS3, Angular Material)
Fabric Js Libraries
Bootstrap, SAAS

I want it to work in codeigniter so I can just call in a load
the header, the desing tool and a footer